# How do I create groups and subgroup1 and subgroup2 Use linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How do I create groups and subgroup1 and subgroup2 Use linq.

Example of this picture

[image: 1]

I want to create json.

Example of this picture.

[image: 2]

I tried to do this but there was a problem.

The items are repeated within one subgroup2.

```
var list = result
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.GroupId, x.GroupName })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        ID = g.Key.GroupId,
        Name = g.Key.GroupName,
        SubGroup1 = g.GroupBy(x => new { x.SubGroupID1, x.SubGroupName1 })
                     .Select(cg => new
                     {
                         ID = cg.Key.SubGroupID1,
                         Name = cg.Key.SubGroupName1,
                         SubGroup2 = g.GroupBy(x => new { x.SubGroupID2, x.SubGroupName2 })
                             .Select(ii => new
                             {
                                 ID = ii.Key.SubGroupID2,
                                 Name = ii.Key.SubGroupName2,
                                 item = ii.GroupBy(x => new { x.Stock_Id, x.Stock_Name, x.Prices, x.ScreenNumber })
                                            .Select(oo => new
                                            {
                                                Stock_Id = oo.Key.Stock_Id,
                                                Stock_Name = oo.Key.Stock_Name,
                                                Prices = oo.Key.Prices,
                                                ScreenNumber = oo.Key.ScreenNumber
                                            }).OrderBy(Or => Or.Stock_Id)
                                            .ToList()
                             }).OrderBy(Or => Or.ID)
                             .ToList()

                     }).OrderBy(Or => Or.ID)
                     .ToList()
    }).OrderBy(Or => Or.ID)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SubGroup2 = g.GroupBy(x => new { x.SubGroupID2, x.SubGroupName2 })
```

You are grouping `g` instead of `cg`.

---

I suggest structuring your code a bit, which would help avoiding this kind of mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your query could be a lot cleaner if you grouped the groups up front, then project out to your desired results.

```
var query =
    from x in data
    group new { x.StockId, x.StockName, x.Prices, x.ScreenNumber }
        by new { x.GroupId, x.GroupName, x.SubGroupId1, x.SubGroupName1, x.SubGroupId2, x.SubGroupName2 }
        into g
    group g
        by new { g.Key.GroupId, g.Key.GroupName, g.Key.SubGroupId1, g.Key.SubGroupName1 }
        into g2
    group g2
        by new { g2.Key.GroupId, g2.Key.GroupName }
        into g1
    select new
    {
        Id = g1.Key.GroupId,
        Name = g1.Key.GroupName,
        SubGroup1 = g1.Select(g2 => new
        {
            Id = g2.Key.SubGroupId1,
            Name = g2.Key.SubGroupName1,
            SubGroup2 = g2.Select(g => new
            {
                Id = g.Key.SubGroupId2,
                Name = g.Key.SubGroupName2,
                Items = g.Select(x => new
                {
                    x.StockId,
                    x.StockName,
                    x.Prices,
                    x.ScreenNumber,
                }),
            }),
        }),
    };
```

The idea is to start off with the most specific grouping first, then one-by-one group the groups by the next layer, and so on.

Comment: Thank you.
Think what you write is very beautiful